# C# Problems With Sending/Receiving Size of bytes (Sockets)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've made these codes to send and receive an Image with a TCP socket but the receive code didn't work.

This is the **send code**:

```
public void SendImage()
{
    int ScreenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
    int ScreenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
    Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);

    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
    bmpScreenShot.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/ScreenShot.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] image = new byte[1];
    bmpScreenShot = ResizeBitmap(bmpScreenShot, 300, 300);

    image = ImageToByte(bmpScreenShot);
    //get the length of image (length of bytes)
    int NumberOfBytes = image.Length;
    //put the size into a byte array
    byte[] numberofbytesArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(NumberOfBytes);

    //send the size to the Client
    int sizesend = sck.Send(numberofbytesArray, 0, numberofbytesArray.Length, 0);
    if (sizesend > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Size Sent");
    }
    //send the image to the Client
    int imagesend =sck.Send(image, 0, NumberOfBytes, 0);
    if (imagesend > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Image Sent");
    }
}
```

And here is the **receive code**:

```
public void ReceiveImage()
{
    if (sck.Connected)
    {
        {
            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sck);
            byte[] data = new byte[4];

            //Read The Size
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            int size = (BitConverter.ToInt32(data,0));
            // prepare buffer
            data = new byte[size];

            //Load Image
            int read = 0;
            while (read != data.Length)
            {
               read += stream.Read(data, read, data.Length - read);
            }
            //stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            //Convert Image Data To Image
            MemoryStream imagestream = new MemoryStream(data);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagestream);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;                    
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i send the size, its sent as 5kb but when i receive it i find it 2GB and this error comes up:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection. An operation on a socket could be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

The error is at this statement `read += stream.Read(data, read, data.Length - read);`

Comment: You should definately tackle the situation where the sender closes the connection while the receiver still expects additional data (`stream.Read()` would return `0` in that case).

Answer (score 0):

I would try getting smaller chunks of data.  In your code you're starting off with *all* the data (2GB at a time in the case that fails.  Drop that down to something smaller--the data is sent in chunks anyway.  For example:

```
read += stream.Read(buffer, read, 20480);
```

this will read about 2k at a time so as to not be larger than the buffer space or be too large for the queue.

If you've allocated a buffer of 2GB in size, your application likely has very little memory left.  The underlying framework is probably unable to allocated 2GB of data for itself (4GB total allocated) to transfer data.

Comment: i know but why does it receive 2GB , its supposed to only receive 5kb

Comment: Are you sure 5k is being sent?  what are the values in the `numberofbytesArray`?  Also, are you sure nothing else reads anything from the stream before calling `ReceiveImage`?  The user of `BitConverter` is right, so the only way you wouldn't get the right values is if the `Image.Length` isn't 5K, or something already read all or some of those bytes which corrupts how you read the lenght...

Comment: YEA IT WAS 5KB , BUT I DIDNT READ `numberofbytesArray` , how can i read the value in it??

Comment: There's something more going on that you haven't provided, the code you posted should work; I'm trying to get the root of the problem--guessing at possibilities because you haven't provide code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: do you think it might be the imagetobyte() function??

Comment: @TarekAdel You said that `numberofBytesArray` has the correct value in it.  so, it shouldn't matter what ImageToByte does w.r.t to this problem. If the other side isn't getting 5k; there's something wrong with the way it's reading the data sent before ImageToByte.  Or something else was sent before the sck.Send(numberofBytesArray,...